# use sublime text api open_file(), but path is not correct

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I want to write a Sublime Text plugin like `ctags` for JavaScript, and I need to to use the [`sublime.Window.open_file()`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window) function.

But it is not working, I have printed path, but it seem different with the path I have transmit to api.

```
print("needOpen  "+needOpen)
root.view.window().open_file(needOpen)
```

console

```
needOpen  C:/Users/lujunhao/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/fis/node_modules/fis-kernel/fis-kernel.js

Unable to open /C/Users/lujunhao/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/fis/node_modules/fis-kernel/fis-kernel.js
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the driver letter (C:) in needOpen?

Comment: Not sure, but i belive that Windows separator is \ and not / as in Linux. And maybe you'd also have to escape the \

Comment: @sergioFC either one will work in Python

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the line where you define `needOpen`. Also, are you sure the path is correct? Try creating a `test.txt` file in your user directory, and opening that instead, just to make sure the command is working.

Comment: root.view.window().open_file("C:/Users/lujunhao/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/fis/node_modules/fis-kernel/fis-kernel.js")
It's work ,but needOpen = "C:/Users/lujunhao/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/fis/node_modules/fis-kernel/fis-kernel.js". then root.view.window().open_file(needOpen). It's not work. Maybe it's caused by sublime text api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem. I make  a mistake with ignore to remove "\n".
The path which pass to open_file is "c:\abc.txt <\n>".It has newline character.
when i print the path , I can't see the newline character. So ............

Thanks to you all

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see your full code, the most likely explanation for

```
root.view.window().open_file("C:/Users/lujunhao/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules‌​/fis/node_modules/fis-kernel/fis-kernel.js")
```

working, but

```
needOpen = "C:/Users/lujunhao/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/fis/node_modules/fis-kernel/‌​fis-kernel.js"
# ...
root.view.window().open_file(needOpen)
```

not working is that `needOpen` is probably not visible to the function calling `open_file()`. For example, if your code looks something like this:

```
needOpen = "C:/Users/lujunhao/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/fis/node_modules/fis-kernel/‌​fis-kernel.js"

def openFile(root):
    root.view.window().open_file(needOpen)

openFile(root)
```

the call to `open_file()` on the last line will not work. This is because `needOpen` is defined in the outer namespace, but since it has not been passed as a parameter to the `openFile()` function, the code inside the function cannot see it. To fix this, pass `needOpen` as a parameter to the `openFile()` function:

```
needOpen = "C:/Users/lujunhao/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/fis/node_modules/fis-kernel/‌​fis-kernel.js"

def openFile(root, needOpen):
    root.view.window().open_file(needOpen)

openFile(root, needOpen)
```

Now, assuming that the definition of `needOpen` and the call to `openFile()` are in the same namespace, your function should work as expected.

---

As far as your question about printing `needOpen` is concerned, Sublime internally converts Windows-style paths to Unix-style ones, so the difference you see is nothing to worry about.